# Ubuntu & PostgreSQL line 24: /usr/local/bin/psql.bin: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have installed Postgresql in Ubuntu 16.10 in this path `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6`

Now if I directly invoke `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/psql` it works fine and prompting for password as below

```
root@neo-linux /u/l/bin# /opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/psql -d postgres -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
```

Now I've configured `psql` as a softlink in `/usr/local/bin` as below

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          28 Oct 31 17:57 psql -> /opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/psql*
```

When I simply call `psql` it's throwing the below error message.

```
root@neo-linux /u/l/bin# psql
/usr/local/bin/psql: line 24: /usr/local/bin/psql.bin: No such file or directory
```

Here is the content of `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6`

```
root@neo-linux /u/l/bin# cat psql
#!/bin/bash

# If there's an OS supplied version of libreadline, try to make use of it,
# as it's more reliable than libedit, which we link with.
PLL=""
if [ -f /lib64/libreadline.so.6 ];
then
    PLL=/lib64/libreadline.so.6
elif [ -f /lib64/libreadline.so.5 ];
then
    PLL=$PLL:/lib64/libreadline.so.5
elif [ -f /lib/libreadline.so.6 ];
then
    PLL=$PLL:/lib/libreadline.so.6
elif [ -f /lib/libreadline.so.5 ];
then
    PLL=$PLL:/lib/libreadline.so.5
fi
# Get the PG bin directory path relative to psql caller script.
PG_BIN_PATH=`dirname "$0"`

if [ -z "$PLL" ];
then
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PG_BIN_PATH/../lib "$PG_BIN_PATH/psql.bin" "$@"
else
    LD_PRELOAD=$PLL LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PG_BIN_PATH/../lib "$PG_BIN_PATH/psql.bin" "$@"
fi
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you installing PostgreSql in this way? Delete the link in /usr/local/bin/psql and install using `sudo apt-get install postgresql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it looks for another file in the same directory, but that isn't there. You could create a symbolic link to `psql.bin` too, but why not set the `PATH` correctly:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin
```

If your problem is the version number, you could do this:

```
ln -s /opt/PostgreSQL/9.6 /opt/PostgreSQL/current
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/PostgreSQL/current/bin
```